# Dagger in library, how to override module methods

Tags: android, module, dagger-2, dagger

I have to create 2 similar apps, where they share common core library module, its not only models, but also Fragment base classes to be extended. FooBaseFragment contains @Inject members, say BaseRestClient to do some networking. It is injected by Dagger

**In app module I would like to subclass BaseRestClient to RestClient** and add some functionality. **This RestClient instance should be injected where core library module @Injects BaseRestClient and also where app @Injects RestClient**

Is this possible?

(Ive read somewhere that you should not override module methods. So Ive tried creating another module with RestClient but that obviously creates another instance)

Comment: Why don't you use separate Modules instead for the only they're not in common.So assuming you have AppA and AppB. Your modules will be AppModule(shared injections), and individuals AppAModule and AppBModule. . .

Comment: If I were to have BaseRestClient in AppModule and RestClient in AppAModule, I would end up with 2 instances instead of 1 singleton, no?

Comment: you can remove the BaseRestCLient on AppModule right? and instead use RestClient in which app's individual module

Comment: of course you should have individual AppComponent so for your AppA:
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, AppAModule.class})
interface AComponent
AppB:
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, AppBModule.class})
interface BComponent

Comment: I am kinda getting lost. BaseRestClient is used inside library. And also as a field @Inject BaseRestClient client inside library too. Is that okay?

Comment: Ow I think I'm kinda getting your problem.. So you want the BaseRestClient to remain at AppModule... What I think you can do is you may use multiple injection of the same class but you will add  annotation @Named("ClientForAppA") on the module... Then in your AppA you can Inject it as


    @Inject
    @Named("ClientForAppA")
    BaseRestClient baseRestClient;

Comment: No I want RestClient to be in AppModule in :app gradle module and BaseRestClient in LibraryModule in :library gradle module

Comment: @urSus found solution?